# shmmax setting in sysctl.conf not taking effect

Tags: linux, redhat, kernel, shmmax

We are running RHEL 4 Update 6 and I am going through an Oracle installation.  As per the Oracle Installation Guide I am trying to update the shmmax value.  As per the guide I have added the following line to /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
 kernel.shmmax = 5319303168
```

However when I subsequently enter the following command to check:

```
/sbin/sysctl -a | grep shm
```

I can see the value is still 1024335872.
If I execute the following:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax
```

I can also see the value 1024335872. 
I have tried rebooting the system, but that still doesn't work.
Any ideas how I can make this setting take effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I know why.  This is 32-bit version of Linux.   Seems maximum value for shmmax in this case is 2GB.

Answer (score 3):

First off, editing sysctl.conf doesn't change the value until you either reboot, or execute:

```
sysctl -p
```

To have it reload the values.

You mention this is a 32-bit Linux.  That puts constraints on how large you can set SHMMAX to and how big the Oracle SGA can be.  See [Installing Oracle9i on FC2](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Oracle/DBA_tips/Linux/LINUX_8.shtml) for more information about the limits you'll run into here.  The largest generally useful setting is this:

```
kernel.shmmax=2147483648
```

And since the one you tried is >4GB that's why it failed altogether.

Many people seem to use some guide or Oracle's suggestions for a setting here as a magic number without actually considering whether the shared memory values really make sense for their system or not.  I wrote the following little script to generate the settings for me on Linux.  As written, it limits the shared memory block to 50% of total RAM, which might be light for your Oracle use; easy to adjust it to a higher percentage.  I hate seeing people set this value to higher than the amount of RAM in their server.

```
#!/bin/bash
mem_bytes=`awk '/MemTotal:/ { printf "%0.f",$2 * 1024}' /proc/meminfo`
mem_max=`expr $mem_bytes / 2` 
page_size=`getconf PAGE_SIZE`
shmall=`expr $mem_bytes / $page_size`
echo \# Maximum shared segment size in bytes
echo kernel.shmmax = $mem_max
echo \# Maximum number of shared memory segments in pages
echo kernel.shmall = $shmall
```

The output from this can get written right to the end of the sysctl.conf, run "sysctl -p", and you're off with a reasonable yet safe setting.

Answer (score 0):

My cobbled-together notes for Oracle show the same instructions.  The only thing I do differently is first I run *echo 5319303168 > /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax*.  I know that's the running config and the other settings would be to make it survive a reboot.

What version of Oracle?  I'm following my 9i instructions and am not sure I run a version of 9i on 4.x.  I'd have to look at the 10g installs since I haven't done one of them.

Comment: Oracle 10.2.0.3 for what it's worth.  Just tried updating directly, doesn't work either:

    [root@hklfcgis01 ~]# echo 5319303168 > /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax
    [root@hklfcgis01 ~]# cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax
    1024335872